# Deleted Django Migrations Folder

Tags: python, django

I accidentally deleted my migrations folders for all my apps including `__init__.py`. Is there any way to reset or retrieve these? Thank you!

Comment: you mean undelete(restore)?

Comment: create a new database and again run `makemigrations` and `migrate` command.

Comment: It's a good idea to keep your entire project (including migrations) backed up and under version control (e.g. git) to prevent issues like this. If you aren't using version control and don't have backups, then recovering the files can be difficult or impossible. It depends on your OS, and isn't really a suitable question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: it may help you https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just create `migrations` folder the folder again, then create `__init__.py` file. After that run `manage.py makemigrations`

Comment: Note that these migrations may be different to the original migrations, in which case your database and migration files may end up out of sync. If you are developing and don't have any important data in the database, it might be easiest to drop the database and run `manage.py migrate` after creating the new migrations.

Comment: Like @Alasdair said, the migrations will be diferent, maybe the best sollution is first do the more external models that dont have foreign keys or it will break (i had this problem while ago)

Comment: Hello! I considered starting the apps all over again but luckily the change was stored in git so I was able to retrieve the missing migration files. Thank you! I will use this as reference in the future